# Создание электронных книг (html,exe)

Tags: html, видео

Делаю книгу из html страничек и захотелось прикрепить в них видео. То есть при переходе в книге на определенную страничку можно было просматривать видео. В интернете нашел кучу примеров с прикреплением видео на html страницу, но они все рассчитаны на просмотр видео в онлайн режиме, а для книги это не подходит.Как сделать, чтобы на html странице можно было просматривать видео в оффлайн режиме (видео находится не в интернете, а на компьютере). Может необходимо скачать какой-нибудь плеер и добавить его в папку с книгой, а в коде, когда добавляем видео, прописать путь к нему... Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону HTML5 - video. [**Подробнее здесь.**](http://htmlbook.ru/html/video)

Имейте ввиду, что тег video, пока, не достаточно кроссбраузерный. В ссылке, которую я Вам дал, есть сводная таблица поддержки данного тега различными браузерами.

Comment: спасибо. Правда, мне в IE но он в нем не работает.

Comment: @Дмитрий Долидов, пожалуйста. Для IE наверняка можно альтернативную технологию прикрутить. Сам не сталкивался, но думаю, что решение должно быть.

Удачи

Answer (score 1):

Вот подборка неплохих плагинов, среди них есть и кроссбраузерные:

[12 плагинов для проигрывания аудио и медиа файлов](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=1282)

к примеру,

[videojs.com](http://videojs.com/)

в браузерах поддерживающих тег `<video>`, использует его, в ином случае - flash.

Answer (score 0):

Отличный проигрыватель видео - [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/demos/). Есть как и бесплатная, так и коммерческая версии. Многофункциональный и гибкий.

На сайте есть подробнейшая документация с примерами встраивания.